# Android graphical login/passcode

Tags: android, graphics, authentication, password-protection

Several of my customers asked me to implement graphical password checker like [image: like here]

Any ideas how to implement this kind of UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to see this: https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/. Guys extracted the appropriate code from android sources and made it easy-to-use in an app.

Answer (score 1):

Well the [android source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/policies/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java;hb=HEAD) is a start. Also have a look at `LockPatternKeyguardView.java`